# arraylist is empty after adding element

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm adding elements from database to this stdData arrayList. I checked it after adding that they are present in stdData arrayList, but when I call this stdData arrayList from another method as you see here it returns null.

```java
package school;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class ReadingStd {
    String conURL = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;" + "databaseName=schoolDB;user=fas;password=24071982";
    List<String> stdData = new ArrayList<String>();
    String std = null;

    public void readStd(String stdId) {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(conURL);
            System.out.println("faisal:");
            String sqlQuery = "select * from schoolDB.dbo.addstudent where sid = '" + stdId + "'";
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            System.out.println("faisal11:");
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sqlQuery);

            while (rs.next()) {
                stdData.add(0, rs.getString("sid"));
                stdData.add(1, rs.getString("name"));
                stdData.add(2, rs.getString("fname"));
                stdData.add(3, rs.getString("dob"));
                stdData.add(4, rs.getString("classs"));
                stdData.add(5, rs.getString("occupation_father"));
                stdData.add(6, rs.getString("edu_father"));
                stdData.add(7, rs.getString("email"));
                stdData.add(8, rs.getString("father_office_address"));
                stdData.add(9, rs.getString("cont1"));
                stdData.add(10, rs.getString("occupation_mother"));
                stdData.add(11, rs.getString("mother_office_address"));
                stdData.add(12, rs.getString("mname"));
                stdData.add(13, rs.getString("cont2"));
                stdData.add(14, rs.getString("caddress"));
                stdData.add(15, rs.getString("paddress"));
                stdData.add(16, rs.getString("sex"));
                stdData.add(17, rs.getString("addate"));
                stdData.add(18, rs.getString("division"));
                stdData.add(19, rs.getString("division"));
            }
            System.out.println(stdData.size());
            con.close();
        }

        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public List < String > returnStd() {
        return stdData;
    }

    public void printstd() {
        System.out.println(stdData);
        System.out.println(stdData.size());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ReadingStd().readStd("czc");
        new ReadingStd().printstd();
    }
}
```

Comment: Was your question resolved?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
        new ReadingStd().readStd("czc");
        new ReadingStd().printstd();
    }
```

The list is a field in the object which you instantiate. But you instantiate two objects which both have their own field `List<String> stdData` and fill that list by calling the `readStd()` method. You call the `readStd()` method of the first object and afterwards you print the list of the other object which didn't fill its own list. This will fix that issue:

```
 public static void main (String[] args) {
            ReadingStd reader = new ReadingStd();
            reader.readStd("czc");
            reader.printStd();
        }
```

Now the object `reader` of type `ReadingStd` fills its list with the values and the same object prints these values.

Answer (score 1):

Your are Actually creating 2 new objects. which cause the problem .
change

```
 public static void main (String[] args) {
        new ReadingStd().readStd("czc");
        new ReadingStd().printstd();
    }
```

to

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
       ReadingStd r= new ReadingStd();
        r.readStd("czc");
        r.printstd();
    }
```